# Simple proof of a basis of space of regular differentials for a hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $y^{2} = f(x)$ be a genus $g$ hyperelliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or any number field). I'm looking for an easy to understand proof that a basis of the space of regular differentials of this hyperellitpic curve has a basis generated by

$\{dx/y, xdx/y,...,x^{g-1}dx/y\}$

I know the general idea but really get confused in the details - especially dealing with the point(s) at infinity.

Any help/references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. What in particular is giving you difficulty? By the definition of genus, the dimension of the space of regular differentials is $g$, so once you show 1) that the differentials you listed are regular, and 2) they are linearly independent, you are done.